# .Net 4.5 System dlls are missing after installing windows8 SDK and restart

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I  am working on MVC3 project in Visual studio 2012 targeting 4.5. Everything was right until I installed Windows8 SDK for Developing Apps for windows8 last night.After restarting Computer, All MVC3 projects have missing dlls.If reference to 4.0 version it just fine but again missing classes and I  have changed targeting .Net version to 4.0  which I do not want at the moment.
[image]

This picture is showing all missing dlls.I tried to find in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies/Microsoft... but I could not find any 4.5 missing dll.
**OS: Windows 7**

Update:

Now I have found 4.5 dlls in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5 but problem is for every Visual studio Project template.There is aslo another problem, System.Linq I have refrenced but Using System.Linq does not recognize this namespace.Can anybody suggest me tool or fix /update patch ?

**Update 2:
Visual studio removal and re installation didn't help ,it is still showing warning errors on dlls.**

Comment: Which Windows 8 SDK? I ddin't think it was supported to be installed on anything other than Windows 8?

Comment: Probably from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx but I dont remember exactly.Installed something showing Windows Development kit in Menu and links to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/aa904962