# System.core dll can not be referenced

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to solve Dlls reference problem in Visual studio 2012. All dlls have set them self in a way they are looking for .net 4.0 version while I can not install because i have already .Net 4.5 installed with Visual studio 2012.I have asked [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405973/net-4-5-system-dlls-are-missing-after-installing-windows8-sdk-and-restart)

but I didnt get a proper answer.Now I am trying to reference System.Core in 4.5 but it can not be referenced as visual studio  is not allowing me to do, it says it will be referenced automatically during project build but actually it does not.I am in catch 22 situation.Kindly advise.
I have reinstalled Visual studio 2012 but it didn't help.

Comment: Where did you get that Windows8 SDK from? A link would be useful. You're running on a Windows7 machine, right?

Comment: Probably fro here , didn't remember the exact link but it was from Microsoft of course. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx.I Have Windows 7 installed on my PC.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zara, I've looked at the download link you provided and it appears to me it's only for Windows8. Windows7 and Windows8 are very different in how they handle things I personally wouldn't dream of trying to install such an SDK on my Windows7 machine.

My suggestion to you is therefore to try to uninstall the SDK and then it might work again. If this SDK only works for Windows8 then there is no use having it installed on your Windows7 machine. Windows7 is good at keeping backups of all files it replaces when installing SDKs and other things so uninstalling the SDK might restore it to what it was before and it might be just fine after that.

If this doesn't make any difference then I would suggest reinstalling .Net 4.5 AFTER uninstalling the Win8 SDK.

Comment: I could not find any SDK "Windows Development Kit " or Windows 8 SDK in Program and features but let me try ,I will let you know.

Comment: If you start the installation program it usually detects that it's already installed and will give you the option to uninstall...could be worth a try. Since the SDK is for Win8 I wouldn't be surprised if that's the reason why you can't find it in `Programs and features`.

Comment: I remember few days ago, first thing I did after getting problems ,I had uninstalled SDK but now I am doing it again using sdk installer but it is unfortunately not giving any option for uninstallation it means it was uninstalled already?

Comment: Then maybe the uninstallation never restored the old files. I would suggest then that you try to reinstall .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 (depending on your needs). And also remove all references to System.xxx files in Visual Studio (you might need to write down the ones you're deleting), restart VS and then try to add them again. I've never had problems with the .Net files but I have had with other external dlls.

Comment: Thanks.Now I  uninstalled .Net 4.5 and all 4.5 mulitarget SDKs after uninstalling visuall studio 2012.Reintall Visual studio 2012.References are fixed only because removal of visual studio does not help until all .net 4.5 versions are uninstalled.Great.